# NServiceBus : Error messages does not appear in Error queue - ForwarderFaultManager does not start

Tags: ravendb, nservicebus

I am running NServiceBus 5.2.14 with NServiceBus.Host 6.0.0

I am using MSMQ as transport and RavenDBPersistence.
All queues appear in computer management except for the error queue.
Everything functions fine for messages and endpoints. Errors are retried 5 times as they should. However after retrying 5 times they do not appear in the error queue.

I have specified the error queue in  as such:

```
<MessageForwardingInCaseOfFaultConfig ErrorQueue="error" />
```

and included in configSections:

```
<section name="MessageForwardingInCaseOfFaultConfig" type="NServiceBus.Config.MessageForwardingInCaseOfFaultConfig, NServiceBus.Core" />
```

Edit1: app.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="UnicastBusConfig" type="NServiceBus.Config.UnicastBusConfig, NServiceBus.Core" />
    <section name="TransportConfig" type="NServiceBus.Config.TransportConfig, NServiceBus.Core" />
    <section name="MessageForwardingInCaseOfFaultConfig" type="NServiceBus.Config.MessageForwardingInCaseOfFaultConfig, NServiceBus.Core" />
  </configSections>
  <TransportConfig MaximumConcurrencyLevel="5" MaxRetries="5" />
  <MessageForwardingInCaseOfFaultConfig ErrorQueue="error" />
  <UnicastBusConfig ForwardReceivedMessagesTo="audit">
    <MessageEndpointMappings>
      ...
    </MessageEndpointMappings>
  </UnicastBusConfig>
  ...
```

Edit2 : endpointconfig:

```
public class EndpointConfig : IConfigureThisEndpoint, AsA_Server
{
    ...
    public void Customize(BusConfiguration busConfiguration)
    {
        ...
        var containerFactory = new ContainerFactory();
        Container.InitializeContainer(containerFactory);
        AutoMapperInitializer.Configure();
        busConfiguration.AssembliesToScan(AllAssemblies.Matching("NServiceBus").And("OurProjectName."));
        busConfiguration.UseTransport<MsmqTransport>();
        busConfiguration.EndpointName(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["InputQueueName"]);
        busConfiguration.UseContainer<WindsorBuilder>(customizations => customizations.ExistingContainer(Container.Instance));
        busConfiguration.UsePersistence<RavenDBPersistence>();
        busConfiguration.EnableCriticalTimePerformanceCounter();
        busConfiguration.RegisterComponents(components => { components.ConfigureComponent<UsernameForwarder>(DependencyLifecycle.InstancePerCall); });

        ...
    }
}
```

I run the endpoints in self-hosting console. In the list of FEATURES I see this:

```
Name: ForwarderFaultManager
Version: 5.2.14
Enabled by Default: Yes
Status: Disabled
Deactivation reason: Did not meet one of the dependencies:

Name: InMemoryFaultManager
Version: 5.2.14
Enabled by Default: No
Status: Enabled
Dependencies: None
Startup Tasks: None
```

I suspect my problem is with the ForwarderFaultManager, however there is nothing listed in the missing dependencies list. What may I be missing? Where could I start looking?

Comment: Do you have a custom FaultManager registered or configured in your code?

Comment: @Hadi : No I have not specified any custom FaultManager

Comment: Are you running visual studio as admin? Can you share your endpoint.config?

Comment: @SeanFarmar Yes I run VS as admin. I have added my config file above.

Comment: Are you self hosting? or using the NServiceBus host? Send me an email to sean.farmar at particular.net and I'll try to help.

Comment: Can you add you configuration code (endpointConfiguration.cs)(didn't get an email from you, so trying to continue here)

Comment: Hi @SeanFarmar : Sorry for not getting back to you. We put this on hold for the moment as we plan to upgrade to 6.0 and hope that would fix this issue as well. I will update the OP with most of my endpointconfig.

Comment: @WPFUser Good stuff, can you try and remove the assembly scanning bit and see if that changes the behaviour?